# Mono Develop 2.2 OSX issue

Tags: c#, monodevelop

I tried a simple:

"what is your name?" "Hello "+ name" app

but when I run the app it wont allow me to input anything....

Whats up with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MonoDevelop's built-in output window does not support input. You must go into project options and enable "Use external console". However, the external console was known to be broken on OS X in MD 2.2, so you need to upgrade to MD 2.4 b2.